# Splitting .txt file in python

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have a .txt file that is separated as follows for multiple rows:
Vermont;VT;Tunbridge;95000204;Republican;John Kasich;36;0.319
When read with pandas I only get 1 column.
How do I split the data in python so that each separated value is a different column in a pandas dataframe
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like this (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html for more)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pf.read_csv('data.csv',sep=';')
print(df)
```

where data.csv is

```
Vermont;VT;Tunbridge;95000204;Republican;John Kasich;36;0.319
NewYork;VT;Tunbridge;95000204;Republican;John Kasich;36;0.88
```

output

```
 Vermont  VT  Tunbridge  ...  John Kasich  36 0.319
0  NewYork  VT  Tunbridge  ...  John Kasich  36  0.88

[1 rows x 8 columns]
```